# Git Hooks error when using NVM in WebStorm and SourceTree

Tags: node.js, git, webstorm, githooks, nvm

I'm using `nvm` with the `--no-use` flag as that was causing my terminal to start massively slow . That means than I always need to run `nvm use <NODE_VERSION>` on new terminal tabs in order to be able to use `node` or `npm`.

I have a project with some Git Hooks configured using `ghooks`, so each time I move to a different branch or commit something, I get different type of errors in both WebStorm and SourceTree, all pointing oout that `node` could not be found. These are some of them:

*SourceTree `checkout`*:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c 
credential.helper=sourcetree checkout BRANCH
Switched to branch 'BRANCH'
M   ...
M   ...
...
env: node: No such file or directory
Completed with errors, see above
```

*WebStorm `commit`*:

```
Commit failed with error
0 files committed, 3 files failed to commit: COMMIT_MESSAGE env: node: No such file or directory
```

In WebStorm, I thought that manually setting the `node` version to use (under `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Node.js and NPM > Node interpreter`) would fix the issue, but it didn't.

I'm using WebStorm `2016.1.3, Build #WS-145.1616`.

Removing the `--no-use` flag would fix it of course, but that's not an option as then the terminal becomes super slow at startup. Any other way to get around that?

Comment: Did you solved that? :\

Comment: No. I'm currently using a different setup and the command-line tools instead, so not having this issue anymore.

Answer (score 10):

Consider using [`husky`](https://github.com/typicode/husky) (maybe also with `lint-staged`) to get more control over how your Git hooks are executed. Basically, you could have all your hooks nicely defined as NPM commands in the `package.json` of the project. Since it all goes into Git hooks, they'll be executed with GUI clients like IDE or SourceTree, at the end.

The issue seems to be related to the system using different paths for the terminal & GUI applications (e.g. WebStorm or SourceTree). With `husky`, you could just define a `~/.huskyrc` and write down what Node version to use, or source `nvm` for that beforehand. I also use `nvm`, and the config taken from their Readme just works as-is:

```
# ~/.huskyrc
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

NB. I'm not affiliated with `husky` anyhow, just enjoying the way it works.

Answer (score 2):

Git hooks is calling node from a non-interactive shell so it's not using the shell environment you probably set in your .bashrc file after installing `nvm`.

Try adding this:  `. $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh` to your `.git/hooks/pre-commit` file

in the end it should look similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash
. $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
./node_modules/pre-commit/hook
RESULT=$?
[ $RESULT -ne 0 ] && exit 1
exit 0
```